# OpenCV findContours destroying source image

Tags: opencv

I writing a code that draw circle, line and rectangle in a single channel blank image. After that I just find out the contour in the image and I am getting all the contour correctly. But after finding the contour my source image is getting distorted. Why this happening ? Any one can help me to solve it out. And my code look like below.

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    Mat dst = Mat::zeros(480, 480, CV_8UC1);
    Mat draw= Mat::zeros(480, 480, CV_8UC1);

    line(draw, Point(100,100), Point(150,150), Scalar(255,0,0),1,8,0);
    rectangle(draw, Rect(200,300,10,15),  Scalar(255,0,0),1, 8,0); 
    circle(draw, Point(80,80),20, Scalar(255,0,0),1,8,0);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours( draw, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

     for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Scalar color( 255,255,255);
        drawContours( dst, contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy );
    }

    imshow( "Components", dst );
    imshow( "draw", draw );

    waitKey(0);
}
```

**Source image**

[image]

**Distorted source after finding contour**
[image]

Comment: Is the first image the undistorted source image ?

Comment: No it is the image after drawContours function. But it is same as the source image

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Documentation clearly states that source image is altered when using findContours.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

See first note.

If you need the source image, you have to run findContours on copy.

Comment: For anyone that struggled to copy the image correctly, try this `cv::Mat imageCopy = image.clone();`

Answer (score 2):

try using 
`findContours( draw.clone(), contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,                CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you are expecting a perfect plot from the findContours and it gives you an ugly drawing.

FindContours is not gonna give an exact plot of your  figures. You must use the drawContours in order to generate a properly image.

Look the reference here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

You can see that the first parameter is Input/Output array. So the function uses the same array to open, modify and saving the image. That's why you are getting a distorted image.

In addition see the parameters explanation. When it talks about the first parameter it says: "The function modifies the image while extracting the contours."

I havn't worked a lot with findContours but i never had a clear image of what I wanted. I must use always the drawContours to get a nice plot of it.

Otherwise you can use the Canny function wich is gonna give you the edges instead of the contours.

Comment: No I am getting the perfect result, but source image getting distorted after contour finding.

Comment: Remember that after de findContours you're not looking to your original image. FindContours overwrite the image with its results. So you are seeing the contours and not the original image, and the contours are not the perfect image.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the second image looks like what I would expect as a result from an edge detection algorithm. My guess is the findContours function overwrites the original image with the result found.

Have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).